# How can i decorate homemade dog biscuits?

Tags: substitutions, decorating, sprinkles

I made a batch of dog biscuits for a Christmas gift, and I want to write the dog's name on them with colored sprinkles.  The biscuits are the texture of over-baked sugar cookies.  Does anyone have an idea of how I can get crystal sprinkles to stick without using a sugar glaze?  Or another idea for a pretty way to put the dog's name on the cookies?

Comment: I am afraid this counts as off-topic :( See http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1108/would-a-question-regarding-making-homemade-pet-kitten-cat-food-be-considered-o

Answer (score 1):

You can use [animal (hide) glue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animal_glue) to make the sprinkles stick, similar to the adhesive on some envelopes that can be licked (or moistened otherwise) to activate the 'stickyness'. The content of the glue is not really that far off from the ingredients in dog food.

Any gelatinous based adhesive would also probably do. While they offer no nutritional value, they are edible.

Non toxic paste, such as used by young school children would also work, but I don't know if the color would ruin the presentation you're trying to achieve. I'd go with the animal glue if you're able to source it. Just melt it down and use a fine paint brush to paint the dog's name, apply the sprinkles and let dry, then shake / blow off the excess.

Answer (score 1):

You could use egg whites, well beaten, (from pasteurized eggs), and a fine tipped squeeze bottle or a narrow paint brush to apply it, then sprinkle and let it dry.

Answer (score 0):

They also make those tubes of icing sugar to decorate cookies that come in all kinds of colors. They look like small tubes of toothpaste and some are even sugar free in this kind of gel form that you can write/decorate very easily with. I've seen them in the baking isle of a well stocked grocery store but also can be found for sure at a craft store such as michaels or AC Moore.

Comment: Thank you all for giving me such great ideas before my question got closed!! :)

Comment: I ended up using a sugar-free gel to write on some of the cookies, and for others, I got egg whites from a carton (the only pasteurized ones available).  I tried painting the whites free-hand, but because the biscuits are dark brown, I couldn't see the whites, so I cut a template of the name on cardboard, and used that as a guide for both brushing on the egg whites and pressing on colored sugar crystals.  All turned out cute, and I'm sure would work well on people cookies, too! :)